# How to get a negative rownumber in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row-number, windowing

I have a set of data with a `DateTime`, say `CalculatedOn` what I would like is to get start at the current date `getdate()` and get an `x` amount of records from before the current date, and the same amount from after.

If `x = 50` then 50 prior to now and 50 in front of now. I was thinking `rownumber()` would be perfect for this, however I cannot think of how to number the rows negative for prior and positive for future.

Also there is the issue of if there are not 50 prior or future what will happen, but that will come after.

Assume the table has just two columns :

```
create table MyTable
(
   Id int not null constraint pk_mytable primary key,
   SomeTextIWant nvarchar(50) not null,
   CalculateDate DateTime not null
);
```

Results :

If today is 25/04 12:54

then

```
Id, SomeTextIWant, CalculatedDate
-- 50 from before now--
-----now here-----
-- 50 from after now--
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your data and the results that you want?

Comment: A way could be to select top 50 with order by ascending and union it with TOP 50 order by descending

Comment: There is no concept of 'before' or 'after' in SQL. Rows are never neither in front or behind other rows, they belong to sets. **You must specify an ORDER BY clause** to allow concepts like 'order', 'row number' and 'rank' into the discussion.

Comment: @RemusRusanu yes of course, It was assumed I would order first by the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two CTE's, one for past and one for future dates, then use `ROW_NUMBER` with `ASC` and `DESC`, multiply  before now with `-1`  and concat all:

```
WITH dataBefore AS
(
    SELECT d.*, rn = (-1) * row_Number() over (Order By CalculatedOn DESC)
    FROM dbo.TableName d
    WHERE CalculatedOn < GetDate()
)
, dataAfter AS
(
    SELECT d.*, rn = row_Number() over (Order By CalculatedOn ASC)
    FROM dbo.TableName d
    WHERE CalculatedOn >= GetDate()
)
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT db.*
    FROM dataBefore db
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT da.*
    FROM dataAfter da
)x
WHERE x.rn >= -50 AND x.RN <= 50
ORDER BY x.RN
```

Comment: How can I get this from one CTE, instead of two CTE for Before & AfterDays?

I am looking for the same results with just a single CTE, Can anybody guide me on this...!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get 50 rows before and after, perhaps this will do what you want:

```
with cte1 as (
      select top 50 t.*
      from table t
      where CalculatedDate <= getdate()
      order by CalculatedDate desc
     ),
     cte2 as (
      select top 50 t.*
      from table t
      where CalculatedDate > getdate()
      order by CalculatedDate
     )
select *
from (select * from cte1 union all select * from cte2) t
```

EDIT:

It is not clear to me from the context of the question whether a row number is actually needed.  It is easy enough to add, thoug:

```
(select top 50 t.*,
        - row_number() over (order by CalculatedDate desc) as rownumber
 from table t
 where CalculatedDate <= getdate()
 order by CalculatedDate desc
)
union all
(select top 50 t.*,
        row_number() over (order by CalculatedDate) as rownumber
 from table t
 where CalculatedDate > getdate()
 order by CalculatedDate
)
```

You can actually combine these into one query:

```
select t.*,
       ((case when CalculatedDate < getdate() then -1 else 1 end) *
        (row_number() over (partition by (case when CalculatedDate < getdate() then 1 else 0 end)
                           order by (case when CalculatedDate < getdate() then CalculatedDate end) desc, 
                                     CalculatedDate asc
                           )
         )) as rn
from table t;
```

You can put this in a subquery and select where `rn` between -50 and 50.

However, I'm not sure what to do about row number 0 and the question provides no information on what to do with any records that match `getdate()` (as unlikely as that is).  I think the first answer does what that OP needs.

Comment: ... and the negative row_number for rows with `CalculatedOn < GetDate()` (title)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter . . . You can see my edit.  It is not clear to me that the OP really wants row numbers on the rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you cannot do order by on the top and bottom of a union all... this is a problem for me.

Comment: @Muhammad . . . That surprises me, but you are right (I guess I haven't done that particular operation in SQL Server).  The version with common table expressions does work in SQL Server (at least on SQL Fiddle).

Comment: I really enjoyed your last query, I didn't know you could define a different order to each partition. That ran faster than what I had going on. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
With myCte
As
(
    Select top 2 column1,column2 from  YourTable where yourdate > '2014-04-23'
    union 
    Select top 2 column1,column2 from  YourTable where yourdate  < '2014-04-23'
) select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by column1) as RNO,* from myCte
```

Answer (score 0):

With RowNumber

```
SELECT TOP 50 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CalculateDate) AS RowNum,
    id, SomeTextIWant, CalculateDate
FROM MyTable
WHERE CalculateDate > @Date

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP 50 -ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CalculateDate DESC) AS RowNum,
    id, SomeTextIWant, CalculateDate
FROM MyTable
WHERE CalculateDate < @Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than splitting and `UNION`ing the tables back up, you could also compute an offset and minus that from the `ROW_NUMBER()` on the whole table:

```
WITH
    base AS (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CalculatedDate) AS row_num
        FROM MyTable
    ),
    offst AS (
        SELECT MIN(row_num) AS row_num
        FROM base
        WHERE CalculatedDate >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    )

SELECT
    base.CalculatedDate,
    base.row_num - offst.row_num AS row_num
FROM base
    CROSS JOIN offst
WHERE base.row_num - offst.row_num BETWEEN -50 AND 50
```

This approach has a few advantages:

1. From my testing, this is about 33% less costly than the other split-then-`UNION` approaches and the same cost as [Gordon Linoff's short query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23292336/8213085) (tested in SQL Server on a small table without indexes)
2. This method returns the 101 rows -- the 50 before, the current/now, and the 50 after, with the current/now identified by `row_num = 0` in the output

   - The split-then-`UNION` approaches only return 100 rows because they're including the current/now row as 1 of the 50 before or the 50 after
   - [Gordon Linoff's short query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23292336/8213085) would need to be filtered on the computed `rn` column
3. It's easy to adjust if you need the row numbers partitioned by another column(s), say an account ID -- just add a `GROUP BY` to the `offst` CTE and convert the `CROSS JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` on the partitioning column(s)